# encrypt a string using SHA512

Tags: vb.net, sha512

Here 's my code and I have no idea why it produces a weird code in the console

(output is "b5?2???p?????'5???.?H???Kun???a??\??d??+\??%??A)?_???j?" without the quotes)

```
Private Sub TestSHA512()

    Dim key As String = "635357773463315343"
    Dim pass As String = "somepasswd"

    Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding = New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding

    Dim keyBytes() As Byte = enc.GetBytes(key)
    Dim passBytes() As Byte = enc.GetBytes(pass)

    Dim SHA As New HMACSHA512(keyBytes)

    Dim resultBytes() As Byte = SHA.ComputeHash(passBytes)

    Console.WriteLine(enc.GetString(resultBytes))
    Console.WriteLine(enc.GetString(SHA.Hash)) 'same...

End Sub
```

Comment: does `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes))` give you something more like you want?

Comment: **NEVER** use `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding` this could cause hash collisions between passwords that are not the same that use characters outside of the ASCII set. Use `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` instead.

Comment: Your question title says "encrypt", but SHA512 is not for encryption, it is for hashing. Which do you actually want?

Comment: There are ascii characters that don't really look like characters (for example most everything < 32). It may just be a display thing. Have you looked at the actual values in the byte array and compared it to results from internet computation sites (just google sha256 computation)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, SHA512 is a hash algorithm, not an encryption scheme, so if you're trying to *encrypt* then SHA512 isn't the way to do it. You'd need to look at an encryption class, such as `AesManaged`.

`ComputeHash` gives you the computed hash as a byte array. You're using `ASCIIEncoding.GetString` to convert that into a string, but not every byte is a printable ASCII character. That's why you're seeing the ??? characters in your console output.

If you're asking how to display the hash output as a printable string, use `Convert.ToBase64String`, which will convert the byte array into a string using base64 encoding. If you were expecting it in hexadecimal, you can loop through the byte array and print the `Hex()` value of each byte.